# pyenv virtualenv does not respect custom prompt

Tags: python, prompt, pyenv

I can use the feature of custom prompt name when using plain `venv`:

```
$ python -m venv --prompt aaaa venv
$ source ./venv/bin/activate
(aaaa) $ deactivate
```

As you see, prompt name was "aaaa", while actual name of venv directory was "venv". I want to use this feature with `pyenv`, because `pyenv` creates all virtual environments within one directory. I need to name it with respect to context of my project. On the other hand, I only use one virtual environment per project, so when it's activated, I want to see just (venv), instead of (name-of-project-for-which-this-venv-was-created).

But somehow it doesn't work when using pyenv:

```
$ pyenv virtualenv --prompt="aaaaaa" 3.10.12 test-env
$ pyenv activate test-env
(test-env) $
```

As you see here, prompt name is still "test-env", meaning the original name, despite the fact I passed `prompt` argument of "aaaaaa" when creating.

Now, regarding just virtual environment configuration itself, it looks correctly. For example, in `pyenv.cfg` there is `prompt = 'aaaaaa'` line, in `activate` there are also lines like `PS1="(aaaaaa) ${PS1:-}"`. So probably the issue lies somewhere within pyenv that does not want to respect my custom prompts.

Is it anyhow connected with [Why is prompt changing being removed?](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv/issues/268)

Some additional info:

- Ubuntu 22.04
- pyenv 2.3.24
- pyenv is loaded via this lines in `.bashrc`:

```
# PyEnv
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
command -v pyenv >/dev/null || export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
```